# send data to a new jsp when user click on a div

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, mouseclick-event

```
<form action="" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <h3>Current Users</h3>
    <c:if test="${!empty pagedListHolder}">
        <div class="data">
            <div class="dataContent">
                <div class="dataText">
                    <div class="dataText1">Name</div>
                    <div class="dataText2">Email</div>
                    <div class="dataText3">Last Seen</div>
                </div>
                <c:forEach items="${pagedListHolder.pageList}" var="user">
                    <div class="dataName">
                        <div class="dataName1">${user.name}</div>
                        <div class="dataName2">${user.email}</div>
                        <div class="dataName3">Last Seen</div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
            <div class="pagination">
                <tg:paging pagedListHolder="${pagedListHolder}"
                    pagedLink="${pagedLink}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</form>
```

Now what i want  is to send data into a new jsp when user click on a div.
How can i do this. please suggest. previously in place of `<div>` i was using `<td>`, than i was able to do it in this way

```
<c:forEach items="${pagedListHolder.pageList}"  var="user">
                <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick="DoNav('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/detailUserView/${user.id}');">
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
```

Now i want same with div. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="dataName">` needs a handler for clicks like your `<tr>` had:

Solution:

```
<div class="dataName" onclick="DoNav('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/detailUserView/${user.id}');">
```